# unable to change the tabs automatically with bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using `nav-tabs` in Bootstrap in my HTML page. They are working but I want to auto move to the next tabs after 10 seconds without clicking on the tab. Can some one tell me how to do it? I found few blogs but that is not working for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/#javascript-behavior you can use javascript to change tabs:

> You can activate individual tabs in several ways:
>
> ```
> $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
> $('#myTab li:first-child a').tab('show') // Select first tab
> $('#myTab li:last-child a').tab('show') // Select last tab
> $('#myTab li:nth-child(3) a').tab('show') // Select third tab
> ```

Combine that with the correct selector and javascripts `setInterval` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to achieve your desired behaviour.